# Automorphisms of a smooth quadric surface $Q\subset\mathbb{P}^{3}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, curves-and-surfaces, automorphisms, quadrics

Let $Q\cong\mathbb{P^{1}_{1}}\times\mathbb{P^{1}_{2}}\subset\mathbb{P}^{3}$ be a smooth quadric surface. We have the following two actions on $Q$:
$$S_2\times Q\rightarrow Q,\; (\sigma,(x,y))\mapsto\sigma(x,y)$$
where $S_2$ is the symmetric group of order $2$, and
$$Aut(\mathbb{P^{1}_{1}})\times Aut(\mathbb{P^{1}_{2}})\times Q\rightarrow Q,\;((f,g),(x,y))\mapsto (f(x),g(y)).$$
These two actions do not commute. Furthermore $h^{0}(Q,T_{Q}) = 6$, that is $dim(Aut(Q)) = 6$.

Is it true that $Aut(Q)$ is the semi-direct product
$$Aut(Q)\cong(Aut(\mathbb{P^{1}_{1}})\times Aut(\mathbb{P^{1}_{2}}))\rtimes S_2 ?$$

Comment: Any automorphism must preserve the intersection product, so it either preserves or exchanges the two rulings. Using this you should be able to prove what you want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is true. This is easily seen by looking for example at the Picard group, generated by $C$ and $D$, the two fibres of the projections. Since $C^2=D^2=0$ and$C\cdot D=1$, the only curves of self intersection $0$ are multiple of $C$ or $D$, and the irreducible ones are equivalent to $C$ or $D$. Composing an automorphism by the exchange of coordinates you fix then $C$ and $D$ and thus act on each factor via an automorphism. This gives the result.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another way to see this. The automorphism group of *any* quadric hypersuface $$Q(x) = 0 \subset \mathbb{P}^n,$$ is exactly the projective orthogonal group $\textrm{PO}(Q)$ of $Q$.

The key point now is that we have the coincidence that $\textrm{SL}(2) \times \textrm{SL}(2)$ is a double cover of $\textrm{SO}(4)$. On taking suitable projective quotients and carefully keeping track of the $2$-torsion, one arrives at the isomorphism
$$\textrm{PO}(4) \cong \textrm{PGL}(2) \times \textrm{PGL}(2) \rtimes S_2,$$
and the result is proved on noticing that $\textrm{Aut}(\mathbb{P}^1) \cong \textrm{PGL}(2).$

Answer (score 0):

You can see the question in this other way. Take an automorphism $\phi:Q\rightarrow Q$ and compose it with one of the two projections $\pi_i\circ \phi$. Then 
$$\pi_i\circ\phi:Q\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^1$$
is a fibration with connected fibers. Therefore $\pi_i\circ\phi$ necessarily factorizes through $\pi_{j_{i}}$ with $j_i\in\{1,2\}$. Associating to $\phi$ the permutation $\{i\mapsto j_i\}$ we get a surjactive morphism of groups
$$f:Aut(Q)\rightarrow S_2.$$ 
On the other hand if $\pi_i\circ\phi$ factorized through $\pi_i$ this means than $\phi$ comes from an automorphism in $Aut(\mathbb{P}^1)\times Aut(\mathbb{P}^1)$. Therefore we have an exact sequence
$$0\mapsto Aut(\mathbb{P}^1)\times Aut(\mathbb{P}^1)\rightarrow Aut(Q)\rightarrow S_2\mapsto 0.$$ 
Now, it is enough to obeserve that $f$ admits a sections to conclude that $Aut(Q)\cong (Aut(\mathbb{P}^1)\times Aut(\mathbb{P}^1))\rtimes S_2$.

Comment: Why a fibration with connected fibres necessarily factorizes through $\pi_{j_i}$ ?

Comment: $\pi_i\circ\phi$ is a fibration over $\mathbb{P}^1$ with fiber isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$. There are just two such fibrations on $Q$, namely the two projections.

Comment: Yes but why? I think that it is precisely the main point of the question. Once you have this, everything follows directly.

Comment: The fiber of the fibration $\pi_i\circ\phi$ is a smooth rational curve because $\phi$ is an automorphism. On the other hand the fiber is the divisor inducing $\pi_i\circ\phi$. Let us write the fiber as $F = aL+bR$. We must have $F^2= ab = 0$. Therefore either $a = 0$ or $b = 0$. The genus of $F$ is $g = ab-a-b+1 = 0$. Then $a =0$ implies $b = 1$ and $b =0$ implies $a = 1$. In the first case we get $\pi_1$ and in the second $\pi_2$.